# How to use pdf.js in vueJs project

Tags: vue.js, pdf.js, pdfjs-dist

I'm trying to use pdf.js in a single page application made with vueJs and the composition API.
I've installed pdfjs-dist and pdfJs (I don't know what the difference is ) but I can't find the propoer way to import it to my components to use it.
Can someone tell me how to do it?

i tried this:

```
<script setup>
    import pdfjsLib from "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf";
</script>
```

but it doesn't work. I get this error: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.

I've also tried including pdfjs through a cdn with a script tag in the index.html... but then, It doesn't work. I try to follow a tutorial, but it doesn't work. I just get errors: numPages is not a function.

Can someone help me oout please?

Comment: Hi, what did you tried so far and what is not working? No way to `import...from...`?

Comment: Hi! I've tried.. but I dont know what to import from where!!

Comment: I also included pdfjs with a CDN into a script tag in th e index.html file. It seams to work, but I can't call any methods in my components.

Comment: Please show us the actual code (edit your question).

Comment: `You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type` tried looking for this specific error?

Comment: yes I did. But  I couldn't find informations I could understand :-)